# Is it possible for a lambda function to create SQS queues from a list of unique names, and assign itself SendMessage permissions for each queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function that creates a bunch of messages. Each message includes in its payload a "type" parameter. I want my lambda function to send messages of the same type to its own SQL queue to be processed.

The caveat is that I do not know the possible "type" values, so I cannot use Cloudfront or Terraform to create the queues ahead of time. So that is why I am wondering if I can do this dynamically within the lambda function.

Essentially, I am asking if a lambda function can create a queue and serve as its event source.

Comment: As long as the Lambda has permissions to create queues and assign the necessary permissions, sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/de/sdk-for-node-js/) in your AWS Lambda function and use it to perform may different operations to manage your AWS resources, e.g. create or delete SQS queues.

You need to ensure that your function has the right permissions to create/delete these resources - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-permissions.html